# P2P webconferancing using html clinets

Tags: applet, webcam, p2p

Can we do a P to P video convercaning wia web based clints . I  have webpages as clinets.Meanns the clint donwloads the webpage rm servere and then allows p to p video converacning beteern these 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, you could do it a with a flash application embedded on your web page.

HTML4 has no support for video.

HTML5 has video support though, but how you would go about implementing a web conference system using plain HTML5 and javascript is beyond my skill.

Comment: let me explain: through my sever both the clint gets the ip address of each other and then they can go for p2 p.is this possible?

Comment: yes it is possible using flex. I believe flex applications can be exported as flash, and can be embedded in the browser. flex applications can make p2p connections.